# Are 'suyo' and 'de él' interchangeable?

Tags: pronombres, posesivos

1 - Can I use 'de él' instead of 'suyo' whenever I want to or only when it's not clear from the context to whom I refer (él, ella, usted)?

> es el lapicero **suyo**
>
> es el lapicero **de él**

2 - Also, is the following sentence grammatical?

> es **su** lapicero **de él**

3 - Lastly, is it possible to use 'de mí', 'de ti'?

> es el lapicero **de mí**
>
> es el lapicero **de ti**

Comment: For some people, saying `detrás suyo` instead of `detrás de él` is incorrect. The [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=hIPWk0joRD6uv1If6f) is adamant about it; the new Grammar documents the usage without judging.

Comment: The *su lapicero de él* sounds positively awful, but given that the preposition *de* can have a multitude of meanings, so long as the *su* and *él* referred to different people, it wouldn't be strictly ungrammatically.  For a nicer sounding example, "su foto de él" would mean person A (=su) has a picture of person B (=él).  Barring a "mismo", they two would, AFAICT, necessarily be different entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ¿*Suyo* o *de él*?

I guess you are asking about the construction ***noun*** *+ de él/suyo*. With adverbs, only the *de él* form is valid (see [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/904/cannot-use-adverbs-possessives-delante-de-ti-v-s-delante-tuyo)). Regarding the first construction, the [Nueva gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGywPAwTfYzfycrU) has the following to say:

> **18.4 Posesivos posnominales y complementos con** ***de***
>
> **18.4a** Como se explicó en las páginas precedentes, los posesivos posnominales alternan con grupos preposicionales encabezados por la preposición *de* y se coordinan también con ellos. Se da la alternancia en las terceras personas *él, ella* y sus plurales, con las reservas introducidas en el § 18.1f (*la respuesta de ellos* ~ *la respuesta suya*; *un primo de él* ~ *un primo suyo*), así como en la forma *usted* y su plural (*un amigo de ustedes* ~ *un amigo suyo*). En cambio, la construcción preposicional suele excluir las personas primera y segunda del singular (<s>*un libro de mí*</s>, <s>*una casa de ti*</s>) en favor del posesivo (*un libro mío, una casa tuya*). En cuanto a la primera y segunda persona del plural, véase el § 18.4e. Los posesivos modificados por el adjetivo *mismo* se aceptan en esta pauta en las tres personas: *de mí mismo, de ti misma, de sí mismos*. Se obtienen así contrastes como *Había una imagen (<s>de mí</s>, de mí mismo, mía)*.

As you can see, the forms *de él/ella/ellos/ellas* and *suyo/suyos* are freely interchangeable, while *de mí* and *de ti* are wrong. One exception that is reminiscent of the [double genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/double-genitive/info) in English is when speaking of photos and the like:

> *Una foto mía* (= a picture of mine) ≠ *Una foto de mí* (= a picture of me)

Another exception is with *verbos de apoyo*:

> Tengo una buena **opinión de ti.**
> Nadie tiene **noticias de mí.**
> Guarda un buen **recuerdo de ti.**

Regarding *de nosotros/nuestro(s)*, both are interchangeable in American Spanish but only the second form sounds natural in European Spanish.

---

## ¿Su __ de él?

The construction *su(s) ___ de él/ella* features a *posesivo doblado* or *double possessive*. This construction can be found in colloquial Spanish in parts of Mexico, Central America and the Andean region<sup>[§18.4h](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wugpKJTdkaYlsDDt)</sup> whith body parts (***su*** *mano* ***de*** *don Esteban*), kinship (***su*** *hermano* ***de*** *mi papá*), ownership and set phrases. However, it is rare when the owner is an inanimate thing (***su*** *ventana* ***de*** *la casa*).

Bottom line: *su lapicero de él* isn't technically ungrammatical, but it doesn't sound too good.

Comment: Good answer. Also, _su x de usted_ is relatively common both in Spain and the Americas (18.4.i), probably as a way to distinguish between 2nd and 3rd person _su_.

Answer (score 0):

You may use also "tuyo", El lápiz es tuyo/el lápiz es suyo/el lápiz es de él, el lápiz es de usted/ You may use suyo when you refer to a 3rd person, Imagine you are talking to Pedro: "No Pedro creo que Carlos olvidó su lápiz, es suyo"